# Determining Hosting Environment While Configuring Kestrel and UseHttps

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

In the ASP.NET Core Main method below, how can I determine the hosting environment, so I can switch between different certificate files for HTTPS?

```
public sealed class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseKestrel(
                options =>
                {
                    if ([Development Hosting Environment])
                    {
                        options.UseHttps("DevelopmentCertificate.pfx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        options.UseHttps("ProductionCertificate.pfx");
                    }
                })
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
}
```

## Update

I raised the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1334).

Comment: I think you can do it only in Configure method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you can use `ConfigureServices` to get hold of `IHostingEnvironment` like so:

```
public sealed class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment = null;
        new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureServices(
                services =>
                {
                    hostingEnvironment = services
                        .Where(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(IHostingEnvironment))
                        .Select(x => (IHostingEnvironment)x.ImplementationInstance)
                        .First();
                })
            .UseKestrel(
                options =>
                {
                    if (hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        // Use a self-signed certificate to enable 'dotnet run' to work in development.
                        options.UseHttps("DevelopmentCertificate.pfx", "password");
                    }
                })
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this and it did seem to work, but you might wan't to double check...

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                        .Build();

        var pfx = config["ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"].Equals("Development", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            ? "DevelopmentCertificate.pfx"
            : "ProductionCertificate.pfx";

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.UseHttps(pfx);
            })
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```